# Highlight several classes starting with the same name. Can't toggleClass back

Tags: jquery

I have several spans starting with the same name, and onMouseOver I need to highlight all that have the same class name.
Example: When I MouseOver span "inner1" I want both of them higlighted.

```
<span class="inner1">Over on this paragraph.</span>
<span class="inner2">Dont over</span>
<span class="inner1">Over on this paragraph.</span>
...
```

I've tried this, and It's almost there, but doesn't toggle the class back. It keeps the "over" class.

```
$('*[class^="inner"]').hover(function() {
    $currentId=this.className.slice(-1);
    $(".inner"+$currentId).toggleClass("over");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0y65db2z/

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?
Txs

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You tell him what to do when you enter, but not when you leave. Javascript doesn't undo by default what you do when entering a jquery hover function. You can pass a second function that will trigger when you leave, where you have to remove the class yourself.

Comment: You can pass a second function which will run when you have mouse out, but className will not work because it'll also have over on it. You should think of a different approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a second callback to the hover function which will run once the mouse leaves the element, but there is a catch in your code:

`element.className` will now be `inner1 over`, so you cannot simply get the `inner1` class to detect what other elements should be changed.

I'd recommend using a single class and a `data-*` attribute to identify the element's "equals".

Check this implementation:

```js
$('.inner').hover(function() {
 $('[data-type=' + this.dataset.type + ']').addClass('over');
}, function(){
    $('[data-type=' + this.dataset.type + ']').removeClass('over');
});
```

```css
div {
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
}

span {
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 5px;
  line-height: 40px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.over {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="onlyThese">
  <span class="inner" data-type="1">Over on this paragraph.</span>
  <span class="inner" data-type="2">Over on this 2.</span>
  <span class="inner" data-type="1">Over on this paragraph.</span>
  <span class="inner" data-type="4">Over on this 4</span>
  <span class="inner" data-type="2">Over on this 2.</span>
  <span class="inner" data-type="1">Over on this paragraph.</span>
  <span class="inner" data-type="4">Over on this 4.</span>
</div>

<span class="inner4">dont hover blue.</span>
```

Comment: Amazing. Now I understand my error. The class name had changed, obviously. 
And your suggestion is perfect. Never thought on using the data-type selector. It works great!!!! Thank you very much!